# Release of NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nszombie

I have based a portion of an app on Apple's CoreDataRecipes example code attainable at

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

After some modifications I spent a good few hours tracking down a bug which I must have introduced, but which I solved by removing two lines of code present in apple's code.

I added an author attribute to the NSManagedDataObject recipe, identical in implementation - as far as I could tell - to other string attributes which recipe already had. My new attribute became a zombie after entering and leaving the modal view controlled by IngredientDetailViewController. The dealloc method of IngredientDetailViewController was

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [recipe release];
    [ingredient release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Having tracked down the bug, I commented out the releases on the recipe and the ingredient (another NSManagedObject) and my app now seems to be functioning. I have now discovered that my code works with or without those release calls; the bug must have been fixed by another change I made. I am now wondering

1. Why was apple's example code written like this originally?
2. What was it about the original attributes of the NSManagedObject recipe which meant  that they were not susceptible to zombification from the dealloc calls?

If the above hasn't displayed my ignorance enough, I should point out that I am new to Objective C and iPhone development but I would really like to understand what's going on here.

EDITED IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS AND UPDATED:

I now cannot replicate the zombie creation by uncommenting those lines, obviously another change during bugshooting did the trick. Some of what I originally asked is now invalid but this has left me further confused as to the use of release for NSManagedObjects, since now functionality seems identical with or without those calls. My main question now is just whether or not they should be there. The crash was occuring upon saving in the IngredientDetailView. Here is the header:

```
@class Recipe, Ingredient, EditingTableViewCell;

@interface IngredientDetailViewController : UITableViewController {
@private
    Recipe *recipe;
    Ingredient *ingredient;

    EditingTableViewCell *editingTableViewCell;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Recipe *recipe;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Ingredient *ingredient;

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet EditingTableViewCell *editingTableViewCell;

@end
```

and the save method:

```
- (void)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [recipe managedObjectContext];
/*
 If there isn't an ingredient object, create and configure one.
 */
if (!ingredient) {

    self.ingredient = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ingredient" 
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [recipe addIngredientsObject:ingredient];


    ingredient.displayOrder = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[recipe.ingredients count]];


}
/*
 Update the ingredient from the values in the text fields.
 */
EditingTableViewCell *cell;

cell = (EditingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
ingredient.name = cell.textField.text;

cell = (EditingTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
ingredient.amount = cell.textField.text;
/*
 Save the managed object context.
 */
NSError *error = nil;

if (![context save:&error]) {

    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. 
     You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the 
     application by pressing the Home button.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"in ingredient detail save after ingredient pop; - recipe.author is %@", recipe.author);
}
```

since I'm a new user I can't put the screenshot of the data model here, so here is a link to it: [data model screenshot](http://deadpunkstudios.co.uk/images/datamodelScreenshot.png)

and finally the Recipe header:

```
@interface ImageToDataTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
}
@end


@interface Recipe : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *instructions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *overview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *prepTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *ingredients;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *thumbnailImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL *isDownloaded;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL *isSubmitted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *uniqueID;
@property (nonatomic) float averageRating; 
@property (nonatomic) float numberOfRatings;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *type;

@end


@interface Recipe (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addIngredientsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)removeIngredientsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value;
- (void)addIngredients:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeIngredients:(NSSet *)value;
@end
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Could you upload your Xcode project so we can check out your code?

Comment: please add some more directions: In which class did you put that release lines, which modal view caused a problem with a zombie.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at Core Data documentation, since Core Data “owns” the life-cycle of managed objects you should not be releasing them at all.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you would release a managed object would be if you had retained it yourself. Seeing as your property definition says that it is retaining the recipe and ingredient objects, when your ingredientviewcontroller is deallocated, it needs to release the recipe and ingredient objects.

When you do something like myIngredientViewController.ingredient = anIngredient, it's like calling a method which would look something like:

```
- (void)setIngredient:(Ingredient *)ing {
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"ingredient"];
  Ingredient *oldIngredient = ingredient;
  ingredient = [ing retain];
  [oldIngredient release];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"ingredient"];
}
```

So in your save method, when it assigns self.ingredient = ..., that is retaining your object yourself - you now have an ownership interest in that object, so you need to release that in your dealloc.

If you think about it in another way, the managed object context has added 1 to the retain count because it has an ownership interest in it, and you have added 1 to the retain count because you want to maintain an ownership interest in it. When you relinquish your ownership interest, by releasing it during dealloc, the retain count goes down 1 and when the managed object context releases it, the retain count would go to zero and it would be deallocated.

That is how normal objects operate, and how you would treat managed objects in most circumstances, but there are a few caveats for managed objects - as the previous poster indicated, the lifecycle of managed objects is controlled by the managed object context, and there are various things that can happen to a managed object that may mean that although the object still exists, it may be deleted in the context, or a fault in the context, or maybe even reused with different data.

You don't usually have to worry about that, but if you use custom managed objects which have their own instance variables that you need to manage the memory for, or other things you want to do when they are created, fetched, turned into faults etc, then you would need to look at the awakeFromInsert, awakeFromFetch, willTurnIntoFault, didTurnIntoFault etc.

But all that is advanced stuff that you won't need until you get into more complex scenarios.

HTH